# Buddy press links not working

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have installed the buddypress Version 2.6.2.

The whole WordPress is working fine but the links to create like add group (buddypress links) is not not working. Other links are working fine.

I searched the whole internet about this issue but still no success.

I have tried everything :

1. setting pages for everything that buddypress wants
2. changing permalinks

The error I am getting is

> The requested URL /wordpress/groups/create/ was not found on this server.

I am running WordPress on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to do after installing **Buddypress**

1. create all the pages for buddypress
2. set the pages in setting section of buddypress
3. flush the permalinks ( go to permalinks and click on save changes.
   Yes, that's it.)
4. turn on the rewrite module in your wamp/xampp server
5. restart your wamp/xampp server

Answer (score 1):

A note for other people landing here because of 404 Not Founds when trying to create or access groups.

One interesting thing about BuddyPress is that it doesn't allow to have core pages as children/parents of each other.

In my case, I had `Activity > Groups`, which didn't throw any error whatsoever, however caused a very strange behaviour around groups where I couldn't create or access any group.

Solved by making the three main BuddyPress pages siblings (or just ensuring they're not parents/children of each other, really).

Page structure:

```sh
# Works fine

 - Members
 - Groups
 - Activity

# Fails

 - Activity > Groups <- This causes the error
 - Members
```

Original answer [here](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/add-group-redirects-to-404-error/), however, I did have to browse a while until I found it, BuddyPress forums are so from the 90s...